# mdSort is undefined in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular-material2

I am working with Angular Material Table. I want to sort the items with mdSort, but when i start the App the table says that the view child of mdsort is undefined. What is the misatke?

My code is the same as in the example here: [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)

here is the error log:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'mdSortChange' of undefined
at AliasDataSource.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/admin/admin.component.ts.AliasDataSource.connect (admin.component.ts:106)
at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk.es5.js.CdkTable._observeRenderChanges (cdk.es5.js:2005)
at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk.es5.js.CdkTable.ngDoCheck (cdk.es5.js:1970)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10897)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12382)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12321)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13182)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13123)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AdminComponent.html:27)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13108)
```

my HTML table snipped

```
 <md-table #table [dataSource]="aliasSource" mdSort>

    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="aliasId" md-sort-header>
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Alias</md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let a"> {{ a.AliasName }}</md-cell>
    </ng-container>
    ...
 </md-table>
```

the class where he say it's undefined

```
export class AliasDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
constructor(private _aliasDatabase: AliasDatabase, private _sort: MdSort) {
  super();
}

/** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing 
the data to render. */
 connect(): Observable<Mailalias[]> {
const displayDataChanges = [
  this._aliasDatabase.dataChange,
  this._sort.mdSortChange, // here is the point where the exception throws
];

return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
  return this.getSortedData();
});
}

disconnect() {}

/** Returns a sorted copy of the database data. */
getSortedData(): Mailalias[] {
const data = this._aliasDatabase.data.slice();
if (!this._sort.active || this._sort.direction == '') { return data; }

return data.sort((a, b) => {
  let propertyA: number|string = '';
  let propertyB: number|string = '';

  switch (this._sort.active) {
    case 'aliasId': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.ID, b.ID]; break;
    case 'adresse': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.FromAddr, b.FromAddr]; break;
    case 'name': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.FromName, b.FromName]; break;
  }

  let valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
  let valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;

  return (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (this._sort.direction == 'asc' ? 1 : 
 -1);
});
}
}
```

my main class of the TS File

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {



aliasColumns = ['aliasId', 'adresse', 'name', 'host', 'password', 'port', 'ssl', 'user', 'menu'];
  aliasSource: AliasDataSource | null;
  @ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;
  alias: Mailalias[];
  isLoading = false;

  constructor(private ms: MailService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log(this.sort);
    this.ms.getAll().subscribe(res => {
      this.alias = res;
      const aliasDatabase = new AliasDatabase(res);
      this.aliasSource = new AliasDataSource(aliasDatabase, this.sort);
      // this.aliasSource = new AliasDataSource(aliasDatabase);
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.isLoading = false;
      const a = AliasFactory.errorObject(res);
      if (a.Status === 401) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Post full error. Console log or build error?

Comment: "after " connect(): Observable<Mailalias[]> {
"add" console.log(this._sort)

Comment: Also check that your are passing sort

 @ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase, this.sort);
  }

Comment: It's passed in the ngOnit but there it is also undefined and he say in the log undefined, too.

Comment: Check the case again
@ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148764/discussion-between-habeeb-and-sebastian-r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So now i found my mistake id had in my div container a ngIf that hide's my table -.-

When someone have the same problem look if you have a ngIf in a tag before !!!

But thanks for the help @Habeeb

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this. don't forget to add `MdSortModule` to you list of imports.

Answer (score 2):

**Add** `MdSortModule` **to your module's list of imports.**

If you are defining an `NgModule`, and a **component** of the module uses `mdSort`, you'll have to update the NgModule's imports as follows:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[MdTableModule,
             ...
             MdSortModule
            ],
     ...
})
export class ModuleThatImportsMdSortModule{}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML

```
 <table mdSort (mdSortChange)="sortData($event)">
```

In TS have the implementation and logic. Refer [example](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples)

**Initial value**

```
desserts = [
    {name: 'Frozen yogurt', calories: '159', fat: '6', carbs: '24', protein: '4'},
    {name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: '237', fat: '9', carbs: '37', protein: '4'},
    {name: 'Eclair', calories: '262', fat: '16', carbs: '24', protein: '6'},
    {name: 'Cupcake', calories: '305', fat: '4', carbs: '67', protein: '4'},
    {name: 'Gingerbread', calories: '356', fat: '16', carbs: '49', protein: '4'},
  ];

const data = this.desserts.slice();
```

**Sorting logic**

```
this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      let isAsc = sort.direction == 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'calories': return compare(+a.calories, +b.calories, isAsc);
        case 'fat': return compare(+a.fat, +b.fat, isAsc);
        case 'carbs': return compare(+a.carbs, +b.carbs, isAsc);
        case 'protein': return compare(+a.protein, +b.protein, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
```

implement the below function too

```
function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: this work but with md-table the example want work by me at the point @ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;

Comment: <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort>
Can you mdSort directive in you html?

Comment: I've update my post with a html snipped from my table. In the ts File he say the Viewchild of MdSort is undefined. But i defined it everywhere :(

Comment: i added also the class where he throws the exception